# Android Kotlin: POST API call with Retrofit is always returning null as response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am developing an Android app using Kotlin. In my app, I need to make a POST API request to a REST API. I am using Retrofit for that. I am following this tutorial, https://medium.com/swlh/simplest-post-request-on-android-kotlin-using-retrofit-e0a9db81f11a. But the response is always returning null. This is what I have done.

I created a class for binding the response data with the following code.

```
data class DeviceResponse(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("nickname") val nickname: String,
    @SerializedName("token") val token: String,
    @SerializedName("phone_number") val phone_number: String,
    @SerializedName("latitude") val latitude: String,
    @SerializedName("longitude") val longitude: String
)
```

Then I created another class to bind the request body.

```
data class RegisterDeviceRequest (
    @SerializedName("nick_name") val nickname: String,
    @SerializedName("device_id") val deviceId: String,
    @SerializedName("os") val os: Int,
    @SerializedName("phone_number") val phoneNumber: String,
    @SerializedName("latitude") val latitude: String,
    @SerializedName("longitude") val longitude: String
)
```

Then I created a RestApi interface with the following code.

```
interface RestApi {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/device/register")
    fun registerDevice(@Body requestBody: RegisterDeviceRequest): Call<DeviceResponse>
}
```

Then I created a ServiceBuilder class with the  following code

```
object ServiceBuilder {
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(AppController.API_ENDPOINT)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T {
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
}
```

Then I created a RestApiService class with the following code

```
class RestApiService {
    fun registerDevice(requestBody: RegisterDeviceRequest, onResult: (DeviceResponse?) -> Unit) {
        val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RestApi::class.java)
        retrofit.registerDevice(requestBody).enqueue(
            object : Callback<DeviceResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<DeviceResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.i("API_CALL", "failure callback")
                    onResult(null)
                }
                override fun onResponse( call: Call<DeviceResponse>, response: Response<DeviceResponse>) {
                    Log.i("API_CALL", "Success callback")
                    val device = response.body()
                    Log.i("API_CALL", device.nickname)
                    onResult(device)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Then I make the request in the activity as follow.

```
private fun registerDevice() {
        val apiService = RestApiService()
        var requestBody = RegisterDeviceRequest(
            nickname = "Waiwai",
            deviceId = "xxxxxx",
            os = AppController.OS,
            phoneNumber = "12345623",
            latitude = "55.12",
            longitude = "43.21"
        )
        apiService.registerDevice(requestBody) {
            if (it?.id != null) {
                Log.i("API_RESPONSE", "ID value is present")
            } else {
                Log.i("API_RESPONSE", "ID is null")
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the code to make the request, in the onResponse callback of the RestApiService class, response.body() is always returning null. But the API endpoint is working as expected. You can even invoke the endpoint I mentioned in the code. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

This is my JSON response

```
{
    "id": 27,
    "device_id": "testing",
    "nickname": null,
    "verified": null,
    "token": "8d48c683-12e7-44d3-88c7-abff45a9f82firdLdkyEy3YZ154c859ebb477d349cdb6e3d6c985996",
    "phone_number": "123456721",
    "latitude": "54",
    "longitude": "0.1",
    "receiver_numbers": [
        "12345672"
    ]
}
```

Comment: can u check what is the status code that returned?

Comment: show your json response please

Comment: @Amitpandey I have updated the question to include JSON response. Please have a look.